# Find user's member of groups in Microsoft AD inside Domain Users security group

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap, ldap-query

I need to find the **member of groups** of a given user in Microsoft active directory using java inside the **Domain Users** group. My AD structure is below.

reg1.subdomain.domain.com
  -Users (Type - Container)
    - Domain Users (Type - Security Group Global)

I wrote the below code. But I was unable to query the users inside Domain Users group.

```
public static String ldapUri = "ldap://ldapuri.com:389";
    public static String usersContainer = "CN=users,DC=reg1,DC=subdomain,DC=domain,DC=com";
    public ArrayList<String> getUserGroups(String username, String password){
        Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, ldapUri);
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, username);
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
        try {
            DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
            SearchControls ctls = new SearchControls();
            String[] attrIDs = { "memberOf" };
            ctls.setReturningAttributes(attrIDs);
            ctls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.ONELEVEL_SCOPE);

            NamingEnumeration answer = ctx.search(usersContainer, "(&(objectCategory=group)(cn=Domain Users)(sAMAccountName=username))", ctls);
            while (answer.hasMore()) {
                SearchResult rslt = (SearchResult) answer.next();
                Attributes attrs = rslt.getAttributes();
                try{
                    String groups = attrs.get("memberOf").toString();
                    String [] groupname = groups.split(":");
                    System.out.println(groupname[1]);
                }catch (Exception e){
                    System.out.println("no members");
                }
            }
            ctx.close();
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return list;
    }
```

Can someone please point out what's wrong with the filter query I have added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the given code snippet above is correct except the searching method that I have specified. I was not able to search the users inside Domain Users group from Users container because I have not mentioned to search in sub directories. By adding search scope to,

```
ctls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
```

it was able to successfully retrieve the users

Comment: Except also the filter you are using `(&(objectCategory=group)(cn=Domain Users)(sAMAccountName=username))` that cannot return any user entries. Or maybe you can explain how an objectCategory=group can eventually match a user (objectCategory=Person) ? Is it the scope ?

Answer (score 1):

The [Domain Users group](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Domain%20Users) is a A Global Group Security Group that, **by default**, includes all user accounts in a domain. When you create a user account in a domain, it is added to this group by default.

Most methods do not reveal membership in the "primary" group. For most users, the "primary" group would be "Domain Users". Specifically, the memberOf attribute of user objects, and the member attribute of group objects, never reveals "primary" group membership. In most domains, the member attribute of the "Domain Users" group is empty, and it is safe to assume that all users belong to this group.

Domain Users LDAP Query Examples for all users that have "Domain Users" designated as their "primary", search for all users whose primaryGroupID attribute is 513 (by default). The primaryGroupID attribute of the group "Domain Users" is the same integer, 513. The LDAP syntax LDAP SearchFilter could be:

```
(primaryGroupID=513)
```

This ASSUMES you have not changed the Defaults and not created any users which have a primaryGroupID that is NOT 513.

For users within the "Domain Users" group JUST use  (primaryGroupID=513) and the baseDN where the users are (CN=Users by default) which will return the DN of the users.

Then to get ALL the groups that these Users are a membeOf you will need to loop through the results using the DN in another query similer to:

```
(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=(CN=UserName,CN=Users,DC=YOURDOMAIN,DC=NET))
```

As shown [All Groups a User is a member of including Nested Groups](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Active%20Directory%20User%20Related%20Searches#section-Active+Directory+User+Related+Searches-AllGroupsAUserIsAMemberOfIncludingNestedGroups)

Oh and normally, the users within CN=Users will also USUALLY be the same as the members within the pseudo-group "Domain Users".

Comment: This is correct. I wrote about this in an article I wrote about [What makes a member a member](https://www.gabescode.com/active-directory/2018/06/07/what-makes-a-member.html#the-primary-group), which includes a little detail about what that number means.

Comment: ok. I changed my filter to NamingEnumeration answer = ctx.search(usersContainer, "(&(objectCategory=person)(primaryGroupID=513)(sAMAccountName=username))", ctls);   Now if is giving me the users inside Users CN instead of Domain Users security group. What I need to know if the way of getting users inside Domain Users security group

Comment: For users within the "Domain Users" group JUST use  (primaryGroupID=513) and the baseDN where the users are (CN=Users by default) which will return the DN of the users.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the base `usersContainer` is set correctly, you just need to change the filter as follows :

- Searching for a *user* entry, you need to fix `objectCategory` to filter users - not groups. You may also use an equivalent like `objectClass=inetOrgPerson`.
- Unless the user entry you are searching for actually really has the attribute `cn=Domain Users` (which is rather unlikely as a user's *common name*), you don't need this part.

So the following should be sufficient :

```
ctx.search(usersContainer, "(&(objectCategory=person)(sAMAccountName=username))", ctls);
```

To match specific user group membership(s) you would just add filter(s) on the `memberOf` attribute (returns matching user entry only if user is memberOf the given group), eg. :

```
(&(objectCategory=person)(sAMAccountName=username)(memberOf=<groupDN>))
```

Note as @jwilleke stated that if you target special groups that don't maintain membership attributes (group:member/user:memberOf), you need to use `primaryGroupID` instead of `memberOf`.

That said, since `sAMAccountName` is unique among all security principal objects within the domain, instead of adding a filter you may just need to use `UserPrincipalName` :

```
(&(objectCategory=person)(UserPrincipalName=username@domain.com))
```

Comment: What I need is to get all the groups inside user's "member of" for a given user name inside Domain User's security group

Comment: This is precisely about retrieving groups a user is member of, which translates to : searching a user entry given its username and fetching its memberOf attribute. The condition 'user must be a member of a given group' is addressed -> add the corresponding filter. As @jwilleke stated, if you target special groups that don't maintain membership attributes (group:member/user:memberOf), you need to use `primaryGroupID` instead of `memberOf`.

Comment: That said, do you really need it ? I mean `sAMAccountName` must be unique among all security principal objects within the domain, then you have also `UserPrincipalName`.